# Remove/hide Firefox title bar in Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.7 

Tags: macos, firefox, title-bar

I've been searching using Google for two days now and could not find an answer.

In Firefox you have the option to remove several bars, like Navigation and Bookmarks Toolbars. Is there a way to remove the title bar?

I'm not talking about the program's OS X bar, just the title bar with the max, min, close buttons on it.

Running Firefox 4 in full screen is not an option, since the menu bar is also hidden then. As for the addon *Hide Caption Titlebar Plus*, this doesn't work on the Mac the way I want.

I don't care if the title bar is removed or hidden, I just want to get rid of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe Megazoomer does what you want? The menubar is also hidden IIRC, but reappears when hovering the mouse pointer near the edge, similar to the Dock.

Comment: I don't know much about the mac version of firefox, but fullscreen and then show the menu bar?

Answer (score 1):

FYI There's a bug on this that is From Jan 2011 and has complications with mouse event handling in the title bar, so I don't think there will be any good work arounds until it's actually fixed.

[Support tabs in title bar on Mac OS X](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625989)

Answer (score 0):

soandoas's answer mostly works. If you go to Full Screen mode and then uncheck Hide Toolbars, you'll get the effect. The potential downside is that you also lose the Mac menubar and dock.